# GmailApp, getDate and Sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have this script that pulls dates for unread messages in Gmail (the idea being that I want to get the date of the oldest unread email)

```
function someFunction () {
    var oldSearchQuery = "in:Inbox is:Unread"
    var oldThread = GmailApp.search(oldSearchQuery, 0, 500);
    for (var inc = 0; inc < oldThread.length; inc++) {
    oldThread.forEach(function(messages){
    messages.getMessages().forEach(function(msg){
    var date = msg.getDate()
    Logger.log(date)
    });
```

However, I want to sort the dates to get the oldest (or, if anyone knows of a better way, just get the oldest unread email). I tried to use sort and reverse:

```
    Script as above but with ----
    var date = msg.getDate()
    date.sort();
    date.reverse();
    Logger.log(date)
    });
```

But it doesn't like it as the values returned by getDate don't play nicely with sort. Anyone got any ideas?

Edit ----------------------------------------------------------

Updated to show current script and output:

```
  for (var inc = 0; inc < oldThread.length; inc++) {
    oldThread.forEach(function(messages) {
      messages.getMessages()
      .forEach(function(msg) {
        var dates = msg.getDate()
        var empty = []
        empty.push(dates);
        var sortedDateList = empty.sort(function(a,b){
          return new Date(a) - new Date(b); 
        });
        Logger.log(sortedDateList)
      });
```

Outputs as:

> [18-06-21 13:49:42:549 BST] [Wed Jun 20 02:08:24 GMT+01:00 2018]
>   [18-06-21 13:49:42:729 BST] [Tue Jun 19 16:15:19 GMT+01:00 2018]
>   [18-06-21 13:49:42:734 BST] [Wed Jun 20 02:08:24 GMT+01:00 2018]
>   [18-06-21 13:49:42:739 BST] [Tue Jun 19 16:15:19 GMT+01:00 2018]

I would be expecting to see:

> [18-06-21 13:49:42:729 BST] [Tue Jun 19 16:15:19 GMT+01:00 2018]
>   [18-06-21 13:49:42:734 BST] [Wed Jun 20 02:08:24 GMT+01:00 2018]
>   [18-06-21 13:49:42:739 BST] [Tue Jun 19 16:15:19 GMT+01:00 2018]
>   [18-06-21 13:49:42:734 BST] [Wed Jun 20 02:08:24 GMT+01:00 2018]

Also, no idea why it is returning 2 lots of dates per mail, looks like its duplicating itself?

Comment: How do you propose one sorts a `Date` object?? Sort is for collections.

Comment: Note that the oldest message in a thread is going to be the first message. The thread order may change based on recent messages (or Google's implementation details) so its probably still wise to check each returned thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't meant to be a full solution to your question, but instead to demonstrate using `Array` functions to get information from messages.

```
function getThreadStartDate_(thread) {
  const messages = thread.getMessages();

  var now = new Date();
  var start = messages.reduce(function (earliest, msg) {
    var msgStart = msg.getDate();
    return (msgStart < earliest) ? msgStart : earliest;
  }, now);
  return start;
}

function getEarliestMatchingThread_(query) {
  const threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  // Sort descending, so we can call pop() to access the earliest one.
  threads.sort(function (a, b) {
    return getThreadStartDate_(b) - getThreadStartDate_(a);
  });
  return threads.pop();
}
```

Example use of the above:

```
function foo() {
  const oldest = getEarliestMatchingThread_("your query here");
  Logger.log(oldest.getFirstMessageSubject());
}
```

Note that there is an implicit assumption that the query you make is not unmanageably large (if it is, Gmail will throw an error). I also make the assumption that at least one thread matches the query. I recommend not relying on those assumptions :)

References:

- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Conditional Operator (`?:`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [`GmailMessage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message)
- [`GmailThread`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread)

Comment: This is super helpful. Thanks, tehhowch!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list the dates for unread messages into an array then you can just run `sort` method on it. For example,
I have an array of dates like this which is same as msg.getDate() as you have shown in the code. I have changed day, month, year and time to make sure it works for all.

```
var dateList = [ 'Tue Dec 18 22:14:59 GMT-11:00 2018',
              'Wed Jul 18 22:14:59 GMT-11:00 2017',
              'Tue Jun 12 02:14:59 GMT-11:00 2018',
              'Thu Apr 12 21:14:59 GMT-11:00 2019',
              'Thu Jun 14 22:14:00 GMT-11:00 2018',
              'Fri Jan 12 22:14:59 GMT-11:00 2018' ]
```

Now you can apply `sort` on this array,

```
var sortedDateList = dateList.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(a) - new Date(b); 
});
```

It will give this output:

```
[Wed Jul 18 22:14:59 GMT-11:00 2017,
 Fri Jan 12 22:14:59 GMT-11:00 2018,
 Tue Jun 12 02:14:59 GMT-11:00 2018,
 Thu Jun 14 22:14:00 GMT-11:00 2018,
 Tue Dec 18 22:14:59 GMT-11:00 2018,
 Thu Apr 12 21:14:59 GMT-11:00 2019]
```

This output is in ascending order. Just swap **a** and **b** to get the result in descending order. You can see output by `Logger.log(sortedDateList);`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, this is what I have done. I created a blank array (`var empty = []`) and am pushing the date var through to that (tehhowch pointed out that sort is for collections). I have tried to use a sort and reverse on the newly filled array, as well as using your way above. But it doesn't seem to be working the way I think it should be?

Comment: What's the problem? Could you please show what you did?

Comment: First get all message dates into array then apply sort on it. You are pushing and sorting at the same time. Take date sorting part out of your **inner** `forEach` method where you are pushing dates to empty[] array and put it in **outer** `forEach`, it will work.